# Trying to send an HTTPS request and get "An unexpected error occurred on a receive"

Tags: c#, https, ssl-certificate

We currently have a third party client that we send some XML too. then we get a return to download a file. I first had to generate a CSR in which we gave to them and they gave us a pb7 file in return that I installed on our server and paired with the private key. I have a C# test that continually fails when trying to send the POST request with GetRequestStream. I have tried to set it to TLs 1.2 and ensured it was enabled on the Server. port 443 is open and listening on the server. The certificate I want is sent, so I am not sure why I cant get the request to go through. The piece of Code causing issue is below. The WebResponse is RecieveFailure. I also did a wireshark trace and I can see it connects over http from their server to ours, but then when ours goes over tcp to theirs it immediately fails.

```
private const string DTTM_PATTERN = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.FZ";
        private const string SS_API_URL = "https://www.example.com/v_6?id=";
        private static string Proxy_Address = "My.Domain.Com";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        var messageID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "");
           var currDate = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString(DTTM_PATTERN);



            string xmlMessage =
          @"The XML is here"
            string url = SS_API_URL + messageID;

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
            X509Certificate2Collection collection = 
            store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, "my.certifcate.com", true);      
            request.ClientCertificates = collection;
            byte[] requestInFormOfBytes = 
            System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xmlMessage);
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=utf-8";
            request.ContentLength = requestInFormOfBytes.Length;
            request.Proxy = new WebProxy(Proxy_Address, 443); 
            request.Proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            try
            {
               //The error appears here on request.GetRequestStream
                using (var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    requestStream.Write(requestInFormOfBytes, 0, requestInFormOfBytes.Length);
                    requestStream.Close();
                }

                }
            catch (WebException webExcp)
            {
                // If you reach this point, an exception has been caught.  
                Console.WriteLine("A WebException has been caught.");
                // Write out the WebException message.  
                Console.WriteLine(webExcp.ToString());
                // Get the WebException status code.  
                WebExceptionStatus status = webExcp.Status;
                // If status is WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError,   
                //   there has been a protocol error and a WebResponse   
                //   should exist. Display the protocol error.  
                if (status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError)
                {
                    Console.Write("The server returned protocol error ");
                    // Get HttpWebResponse so that you can check the HTTP status code.  
                    HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webExcp.Response;
                    Console.WriteLine((int)httpResponse.StatusCode + " - "
                       + httpResponse.StatusCode);
                }
            }
```

Comment: I had this error a few months ago in a service that had been running for months.. The problem was with the Tls12 certificates The exact code I used was : `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;`

Comment: Yeah that seems to be the common solution, but sadly I have tried that and it does not work.

Comment: Have you tried `request.KeepAlive = false;`? That seems to be another solution.

Comment: I did try that too both ways and did not get it to work.

Comment: 1) Set up your own HTTPS server (even a mocking server) so that you can test it without your third party. That can easily rule out common mistakes if you happen to make. 2) Learn tools like Wireshark so that you can easily capture and analyze SSL/TLS handshakes. The actual packets can tell a lot on what might be the cause.